# Adding a field value to an Account, before converting the lead

Tags: lead-conversion

I have customized the lead conversion process, if i click on the button it will show all the duplicate Accounts on the popup window. There i have added 2 buttons **Ignore & Create**, **Choose Selected**. If i click on the Ignore & Create button it display a input text field called reason(field is in Account). Here my question is, while converting the lead to an account how can can i pre-populate the reason on the account.

Currently  i am doing the Lead conversion & then updating the Account. So i am using 2 DML statements. Is there any way to do it with Single DML.

Answer (score 2):

In your use case, this is not possible. Because for lead conversion you are doing  something like

```
Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(myLead.id);

LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
```

You can't merge another DML with this so you need 2 separate DML here.

In general, you can create generic sObject List and add multiple type (with fixed limit 10) of sobject in that and can update all of them in single DML.